# Do Domination powers make memory permanently irrecoverable?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem-2e

If a Vampire dominates a person into forgetting something is the memory lost permanently? or are they just unable to access it normally? could hypnosis, a spell, or other memory reading power recover it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. In the list of Conditions, "False Memories" is covered on page 303. The resolution listed is "Face proof that your memory is false and succeed at the breaking point." Other than that, barring Storyteller fiat, the memories are altered as per the user's desires.
2. It's worth noting, though, that as per the descriptions of "Mesmerize" and "Lying Mind," you're not really "dominating them into forgetting" anymore. You're replacing old memories with new ones, even if that's a blank swath of time. The reason I bring it up is that "forgetting" isn't something you can Command someone to do, in that it's not like the natural act of, say, forgetting where you left your keys. So, yes. The memories are permanently lost.

Answer (score 2):

**They're recoverable.**

Checking, the Amnesia Condition (p301) says its Resolution is "You regain your memory and learn the truth." Which is... awful circular in definition (you regain your memory by regaining your memory?) and unhelpful.

But there are definitely ways to recover supernaturally-forgotten memories: A **Clash of Wills** (p125) occurs when two supernatural powers contradict each other. An ability or spell that can read or recover memories will have a chance at a contested roll to break through the victim's otherwise-permanent memory loss.

Vampires themselves have such an ability: **Lay Open The Mind**.

> By focusing, the vampire can drag up a full memory from the
>   victim, including things that the victim has forgotten or that
>   were suppressed by magic (though doing so takes a Clash of
>   Wills).

The 1e book *Second Sight* contains the **Hypnotic Voice** Merit (p66) for mere mortals:

> The character can
>   hypnotize anyone given the opportunity, but it is much
>   easier if the subject is willing. While in a hypnotic trance,
>   a subject can be given suggestions or forced to confront
>   repressed memories, possibly memories stolen by vampiric
>   Disciplines or repressed due to Lunacy triggered by were-
>   wolves, or Disbelief invoked by vulgar magic.